# Unable to move the brand to its own line above navigation in Bootstrap 3 navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I feel as if this should be a simple task, but I haven't been able to find a solution or even anyone who seems to be having the same problem. I basically just want the brand on a separate line above the main navigation while remaining inside the navbar (or at least looking like it does).

I've tried to achieve this by messing with clears (for the navbar-brand and/or navbar-nav classes), moving the brand around within the navbar, completely removing it and placing it before the navbar in the HTML (also replacing it with a plain h1 element since I imagine that class is really only meant to be used within a navbar)...

Everything I do either makes no visible changes or throws the alignment off somehow. I've managed to throw off the line-height of the navbar so that the backgrounds of the navigation links don't reach all the way to the top, moved the contents of the navbar left and right, etc.

I have this:

**Brand** Menu Item | Menu Item | Menu Item | Menu Item | Menu Item

I want this:

## Brand

Menu Item | Menu Item | Menu Item | Menu Item | Menu Item

Right now, the code I have is pretty close to what you get straight out of the box:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#top-nav-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="top-nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

Similarly, I've done very little with the CSS (changing the display didn't have a visible effect):

```
.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 40px;
  display: block;
}
```

Hopefully, [this pen](http://codepen.io/epsilonx2/pen/sgKxv) will be more helpful.

I honestly feel as if I must be missing something terribly obvious, but most of the related posts I've seen have the opposite problem, usually too many links breaking onto two lines when the person only wants one. I'd truly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: either give us enough code to reproduce the problem or put it in a [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) or both, preferably. In other words, include the css that goes with this html

Comment: Cant you increase the height of the navbar  and use absolute position for .navbar-nav class? In addition, you can also make the toggle icon float on the left or use absolute positioning. Your navbar will work both in desktop and mobile then.

Comment: @ChrisM I've never used jsFiddle, but I threw everything in a pen and added a link. It's almost entirely Bootstrap, very little customization other than what I included initially. I understand, though, there might be something I'm missing lurking in other bits of code.

Comment: Is "Title" == "Brand"?  Please be explicit!

Comment: please put only the relevant code to reproduce the problem! we don't need every media query in your css

Comment: @ChrisM Yes. I refer to it as "brand" because that's the class name (navbar-brand). I'm sorry if this is irritating to you... I'm attempting to learn here on a few different fronts and clearly making plenty of mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on line 3820 of you code in your media query for `min-width: 768px` you need to add:

```
.navbar-nav {
    clear: left;
}
```

since you have a responsive site, you may need to make other adjustments as well

once you declare a `float`, the elements following it will continue from there.  if you `float:left`, everything after will continue flowing to the right until your width is filled. to stop this you need to clear the float. if the preceding element is `float:left` you need to `clear:left` and vice versa.  you can simply use `clear:both` when you don't know which float is preceding

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your patience. I knew it had to be something small like that!

Comment: no problem. I will clarify the answer for you. give me a minute.